# F# - Print match expression result

Tags: f#, match

I think this will be simple but I've spent the past hour trying everything I can think of and researching online to no avail.
(I'm new to F#)

I have the following code which sends a HTTP Request, it then matches the result. If it doesn't match anything ( | _ ) I want to just print its string value to console. How would I go about doing this?

```
    match Http.RequestString("http://foo.com/res.php", 
                          httpMethod = "GET", 
                          query = ["key", key; "action", "get"; "id", id]) with
     | "CAPCHA_NOT_READY" -> printfn "Sleeping for 5"
                             Thread.Sleep(5000)
                             GetCaptchaRequest id
     | _  -> printfn ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underscore character is used when you don't care about the value and won't be using it in subsequent code. You just need to give the variable a name. Try this:

```
| msg -> printfn "%s" msg
```

In this example, I've chosen `msg` as the variable name but it can be any valid variable name you choose.

Since all the branches of a `match` statement must return the same type, you will need more than just the `printfn` statement. In cases like this, where the external call could potentially fail, it is a common idiom to use the `Option<'a>` type to represent success or failure.

Not knowing the specifics of your API endpoint, consider this pseudocode:

```
let GetCaptchaRequest id : string option =
        match Http.RequestString("http://foo.com/res.php", 
                              httpMethod = "GET", 
                              query = ["key", key; "action", "get"; "id", id]) with
         | "CAPCHA_NOT_READY" -> printfn "Sleeping for 5"
                                 Thread.Sleep(5000)
                                 GetCaptchaRequest id
         | "ERROR" -> printfn "Something went wrong!"
                      None
         | result  -> printfn "Successful result!"
                      Some (parseMyCaptchaResult result)
```

Comment: Thank you, That makes sense. Though I seem to be having issues with types in F#. When I adjust to your code I get an error saying its expecting a type unit and not string? Yet if i pipe Printfn "%a" to the end of my HTTPRequest, it will print the string? but i can't use "%a" in this match as its expecting msg is a string?

Comment: Each branch of a `match` statement must return the same type. `printfn` returns unit `()`, whereas I'm guessing `GetCaptchaRequest` returns a `string`. You could use the `Option<'a>` type to indicate success or failure. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: I've added suggestions on overcoming the type problem with use of the `Option<'a>` type

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you very much. I don't think I have enough REP yet to mark you as 'Right answer' So i just upvoted it instead. Thank you again.

Comment: @user3717174 - You always have enough rep to mark someone's answer as the right answer: just check the checkmark under the answer's score. It will turn green when you do so. That's not a privilege you gain with increasing reputation points, it's something every account, even a newbie account with 1 rep point, is allowed to do.